# Refactoring c# : How to remove duplicated code when properties to update differ in each case

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-duplication

After hacking about for a little while on a prototype I've ended up with number of methods that update boolean flags on an object and then update interface and do some processing based on the new value. These are pretty much all the same - but the value they update is different

for example - imagine we have a bunch of colored boxes to update - I might have some methods that look like this:

```
        protected void SetBlueBoxVisibility(bool blueBoxVisibility)
    {
        Project project = LoadProject();
        project.ShowBlueBox = blueBoxVisibility
        ReDrawSomeThings();
        CalcualteSomeStuff();
        Project.UpdateBoxStatus();
        SaveProject(project);
        ShowBlueBoxPanel(blueBoxVisibility);
        RaiseStatusUpdated();
    }

    protected void SetRedBoxVisibility(bool redBoxVisibility)
    {
        Project project = LoadProject();
        project.ShowRedBox = redBoxVisibility
        ReDrawSomeThings();
        CalcualteSomeStuff();
        Project.UpdateBoxStatus();
        SaveProject(project);
        ShowRedBoxPanel(redBoxVisibility);
        RaiseStatusUpdated();

    }
```

Now, obviously - most of that stuff is repeated - which is a pain when I come to change anything. Particularly if I end up with twenty different box colors rather than just two!

I was thinking that there must be a way to strip out the code that changes and gather the stuff that's the same in a more generic method - but I'm having trouble getting to quite how to do that.

I've heard of closures - but I haven't gotten my head around them enough to know if they would help here.

I was thinking possible the following might be on the right line - but I'm I don't know how to tell the generic method which property to operate on - **[Project Variable To Update]**

```
        protected void SetRedBoxVisibility(bool redBoxVisibility)
    {
        SetGenericBoxVisibility([Project Variable To Update],redBoxVisibility)
        ShowRedBoxPanel(redBoxVisibility);
        RaiseStatusUpdated();   
    }

    protected void SetBlueBoxVisibility(bool blueBoxVisibility)
    {
        SetGenericBoxVisibility([Project Variable To Update],blueBoxVisibility)
        ShowBlueBoxPanel(blueBoxVisibility);
        RaiseStatusUpdated();   
    }

    protected void SetGenericBoxVisibility([Project Variable To Update], boxVisibility)
    {
        Project project = LoadProject();
        project.**[Project Variable To Update]** = boxVisibility
        ReDrawSomeThings();
        CalcualteSomeStuff();
        Project.UpdateBoxStatus();
        SaveProject(project);
    }
```

Any pointers as to how to handle this kind of thing would be useful :)

Comment: You should read up on basic OO principles.

Comment: @Jack - maybe you should provide some guidance or at least point out where you think the problem might lie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you *could* extract it like this:

```
protected void SetGenericBoxVisibility(Action<Project> propertySetter,
                                       Action<bool> panelShower,
                                       bool boxVisibility)
{
    Project project = LoadProject();
    propertySetter(project);
    ReDrawSomeThings();
    CalculateSomeStuff();
    Project.UpdateBoxStatus();
    SaveProject(project);
    panelShower();
    RaiseStatusUpdated();
}
```

Then:

```
protected void SetBlueBoxVisibility(bool blueBoxVisibility)
{
    SetGenericBoxVisibility(project => project.ShowBlueBox = blueBoxVisibility,
                            () => ShowBlueBoxPanel(blueBoxVisibility));
}

protected void SetRedBoxVisibility(bool redBoxVisibility)
{
    SetGenericBoxVisibility(project => project.ShowRedBox = redBoxVisibility,
                            () => ShowRedBoxPanel(redBoxVisibility));
}
```

It's not *terribly* nice, admittedly...

Comment: Thanks :-) I've had a little play with some code and this looks to be a really useful - it's a new bit of syntax for me to explore - now I shall go and use what I have learned on something more exciting than showing colored boxes :-)

Comment: @Girl Called Pete: Oh yes, lambda expressions are incredibly useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have bigger problems - one method per box to update simply doesn't fit.  You have SetGenericBoxVisibility but then undo any good work by continuing to have Set*BoxVisibility methods.  I don't know which technology you're using - if it's WPF look into MVVM then you can simply update your ViewModels.  If it's WinForms you should create some kind of dictionary perhaps - `Dictionary<BoxType, Box> _boxLookup` where `BoxType` is an enum of the types you define.  Then to set box visibility, you do `_boxLookup[BoxType.Red].Property = value;` or you could have methods to manipulate a box take a `BoxType` parameter.

However, some more context would be very useful, since even that solution isn't ideal.  Moving some other code or getting some insight into the bigger picture about the problem you are solving with multiple boxes should lead to a few more 'aha' moments..

Comment: :) I'm just kinda learning the principles really (seems there are many ways to skin a cat). The actual context where this came up was having a bunch of checkboxes on a webform and using the OnCheckedChanged method on each box to do some processing (including updating a boolean flag on an object). Having one generic checkbox updated method to handle the event might be a way to go - I guess the next trick for that is working out which flag to update by looking at the sender that gets passed to the event.

Answer (score 1):

I think to really refactor this you need to make an IBox interface.  Basically, that interface acts as a contract defining what methods and properties all Box objects must have at the very least.

```
interface IBox {
 //your generic properties and method stubs
 Bool visibility;
}
```

Now, implement the interface for each of your 'boxes'

```
class blueBox : IBox
{
 //here you will have your concrete implementations of the above methods and properties
public Bool visibility   {get; set;} // this doesn't make sense with auto getter setters. you would need to write your bluebox specific getter and setters

}

class redBox : IBox
{
//more concrete implementation

}


public myMethod_To_Do_Stuff(IBox myBox) { // see how I am passing the interface not the conrete classes

myBox.visibility = true;

}
```